# How can I remove edittext error and request focus in android?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

When I set error and request focus on edittext  then it sets an error and request focus but how can I remove error and remove focus ?

```
mEditTextSearchOrAdd.setError("Error");
mEditTextSearchOrAdd.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should do the following :

```
mEditText.setError(null);//removes error
mEditText.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Example
=======
xml
---
 <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />


java
-----
private EditText EditText1;
username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
username .setError(null);
```