# How do I delete setError exclamation mark after focus change?

Tags: android, android-edittext, onfocus

I have an EditText line that uses setError code to validate user input.  If the EditText line is left blank and the user tries to leave the Activity, a setError message shows as expected just below the EditText line (Pic 1).

[image: Pic 1]

As soon as the user begins to add text on the EditText line the setError exclamation point and message disappear as expected.  However, if the user just moves the focus away from the EditText line to another EditText line, the setError exclamation point remains (Pic 2).

[image: Pic 2]

I want the exclamation point to disappear on any focus change away from the EditText line.  Any ideas on how to fix?

partial Activity file:

```
...
public void onClickSave(View v) {
    int stringToDo = cEditText.getText().toString().replace(" ", "").length();
    if (stringToDo > 0) {
        cEditText.setError(null);
        Toast saveToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked the SAVE Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        saveToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        saveToast.show();
    }
    else {
        cEditText.requestFocus();
        cEditText.setError("Add a To Do Item");
    }
}
```

Comment: Its basic. just you have to `setError(null);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove error from EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206799/remove-error-from-edittext)

Comment: The setError(null) removes the error when focus moves away from the cEditText so that definitely helps.  But how do I get the setError message to show when then cEditText has focus to begin with and the user clicks "Save"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an onFocusChanged listener, and set the error to whatever you need, based on the focus state. (`null` to get rid of it)

```
cEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // Sets the error message if the EditText has focus and removes it if it doesnt
        cEditText.setError(hasFocus ? "Add a To Do Item" : null);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.  The "?" means set the error text if the EditText has focus and if not, then "null" to get rid of it?

Comment: Correct, it's just shorthand for an if else block

Comment: Didn't work, no error message was returned.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, `setError(null)` should definitely remove the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13195876/2278598

Comment: Ok, so just need to fix one thing.  Focus is on the cEditText when the Activity opens.  When "Save" is clicked the setError message does not show.  However, when focus moves away to another EditText line and then back to the cEditText line (the focus has changed) the setError message appears as expected.  So I just need to determine how to have setError message launch if user clicks "Save" and focus is already on the cEditText line.

Comment: Just had to add setError and requestFocus before Listener to your rec.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your onCreate() after onClickSave(){}

```
cEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                cEditText.setError(null);

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: I think it assumes text gets changed.  I am trying to add code for when the EditText lines are empty and the user clicks save.  So the setError message never launches because no text is changed.

Comment: In this, When your edit text is empty and user click on button then edittext shows error dialog and when you click on it and write something, error dialog will disappear.

Comment: It didn't show error dialog when the edittext was empty and the user clicks on the save button.

Comment: try int stringToDo = cEditText.getText().toString().trim().replace(" ", "").length();

Comment: because may b if only space is there , you will get length() > 0.